# How to listen to change between fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-livedata

I tried to find an easy way to listen to fragment changes from my activity in order to hide/show the drawer menu button from my LoginFragment and I could not find a good and easy way to implement for my case here in sfo, so I would like to share an easy solution I eventually came up with using `ViewModel` and a `LiveData` which saves the fragment class name that is currently displayed and observing it from the activity to listen for changes.

**NOTE** the solution works in case that your fragments are displayed on the same `FragmentContainerView` in your layout

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exmaple:

ViewModel class :

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel(){

   val currentFragment = MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

Now set `currentFragment` value inside your fragments:

```
class LoginFragment() : Fragment() {

private lateinit var : viewModel : MyViewModel
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        ViewModel.currentFragment.value = this::class.java.name
   }
}
```

```
class MainFragment() : Fragment() {

private lateinit var : viewModel : MyViewModel
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
        ViewModel.currentFragment.value = this::class.java.name
   }
}
```

Now in your Activity you can observe `currentFragment` and do whatever you want(in my case I wanted to know if the current fragment is LoginFragment and hide the drawer menu button from the toolbar) :

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mapViewModel.currentFragment.observe(this, {
            when (it) {
                LoginFragment::class.java.name -> {
                    //your stuff related to LoginFragment
                }
                MainFragment::class.java.name -> {
                    //your stuff related to MainFragment
                }
            }
        })
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps anyone ^^